# Multiline Caption for Button in Vaadin does not work

Tags: java, css, vaadin, multiline

I am using Vaadin and I want to add a caption to a button that has multiple lines - it should simply display `String - 2 linebreaks - String` which I did not expect to be too hard to do.

Now sadly this turns out to be a little bit harder than I expected - My DataStructure should display a timetable (so I am using a structure that extends a grid) and I want all Slots to be filled with the according lectures and lectureres. However I am bound to use the Button-Element (not the NativeButton), so using a HTML-Caption does not work.

So what I tried was a css-class like this:

```
.multiline-button {
    width: 125px;
    white-space: normal !important;
    height: auto;
    word-break: break-word !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

(actually the background-color was just for testing if the style was applied) - I also tried setting these attributes manually in code via `button.setStyle(name, value);`. Sadly none of those turns out to even be applied to the button. My Button Creation Code:

```
@CssImport("./styles/multiline-button.css")
public class NewScheduleTimetable<T> extends TimetableWithValue<T> {

    @Override
    protected Button createSlot(int day, int timeSlot) {
        final Button slotButton = new Button();
       /* even desperately tried removing all other themes, didn't even change anything 
        slotButton.getThemeNames().forEach(theme -> {
            slotButton.removeThemeName(theme);
        }); */
        slotButton.setWidthFull();
        slotButton.setHeight("125px");
        slotButton.addClassName("multiline-button");

        //this sets the text
        if (hasValue(day, timeSlot)) {
            slotButton.setText(getText(getValue(day, timeSlot)));
        }
        this.recalculateColumnWidths();
        return slotButton;
    }

}
```

Now the Buttons get created successfully and also display the name they should have - they are just missing the linebreaks for the captions. If I inspect the element in my browser, the captions do contain linebreaks (linebreaks are done via `\n`).

So I am quite new to Vaadin, but usually these things are a five-minuter and not take me days to figure out different approaches (which all did not work out sadly) - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is set some HTML content as the icon component, although the button doesn't seem to be designed for this.

`Button button = new Button(new Html("<div>Line 1<br /><br />Line 2</div>"));`

Note that it's important that the Html content is contained within one element, like the `div` above.

This also adds the `icon` theme that you might want to remove with `button.getThemeNames().remove("icon");`.

You don't have to, if you change your CSS to e.g.

```
height: auto;
padding: var(--lumo-space-s);
```

it should get you pretty far.